# How to show a javascript alert and close the browser tab on button click

Tags: development, web-part, javascript, event-handlers

I have a web part with button that is clicked upon approval of a workflow. I want to add a JavaScript alert after performing all the button click c# code and then upon closing the alert the browser tab has to be closed.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should write the javascript code into the page through C# after doing all the other operations you want to do when the button is clicked.

It should  work that way:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ... your code ...

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "myscript", "alert('test');Window.close()", true);
}
```

Comment: I did try your chunk of code.. I was successful in getting the alert, however the Window did not close!

Comment: window.close might not work correctly in every browser.
Try this workaround:
window.open('', '_self', '');
window.close();